# How to vectorize this replacement operation?

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, apply

I have a dataset that needs to be capped/trimmed etc. based on values from another dataset. Both datasets have same structure (column names etc.).

What is a quick way to apply the transformations stored in another dataset to the current dataset?

Sample data:

```
#generate sample data & set some values to NA
#this is the dataset that has variables that need to be trimmed
x1 <- data.frame(a=rep(11:20), b=rep(41:50))
x1[2,1] <- NA
x1

#a vector containing values to trim to (in this case, say 75th percentile)
y1 <- apply(x1, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm=T))
y1

#I am doing this inside a loop
for (i in 1:ncol(x1)){
  x1[is.na(x1[[i]]),] <- y1[i]       #if missing, set to some value

  x1[x1[[i]] > y1[i], i] <- y1[i]    #if larger than 75th pctl, set to some value
}

x1
```

I am pretty sure there is a faster vectorized way to do this. I'd greatly appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: write your logic as a function that takes a vector and a value:

```
myfun <- function(x, y) {
    x[is.na(x)] <- y
    x[x > y] <- y
    return (x)
}
```

Then use `mapply` which will treat `x1` as a list of columns (which it sort of is):

```
mapply(myfun, x1, y1)
```

And you can coerce it back to a `data.frame` by wrapping it:

```
data.frame(mapply(myfun, x1, y1))
```

You could also add `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` if you want...

---

As per the comments, `Map` is a better choice here since it avoids some typing and probably some overhead:

```
as.data.frame(Map(myfun, x1, y1))
```

Comment: Yes, you need `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` or some columns might be converted to a different type. Also note that `as.data.frame(mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE))` is equivalent to the shorter `as.data.frame(Map(...))`.

Comment: I always forget about `Map` and `Reduce`!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using the `data.table` package. `data.table` is very fast and has powerful syntax, but the disadvantage is the need to learn new syntax.

```
library(data.table)

x1 <- data.frame(a=rep(11:20), b=rep(41:50))
x1[2,1] <- NA

# Convert data.frame to data.table.
DT <- data.table(x1)

# Put your desired operations into a function, for clarity/tidiness.
update_vals <- function(x, prob=0.75) {
    xcut <- quantile(x, probs=prob, na.rm=TRUE)
    x[is.na(x) | x > xcut] <- xcut
    return(x)
}

# Use lapply and data.table syntax to 'loop' over columns.
DT2 = DT[, lapply(.SD, update_vals)]
DT2
#      a     b
#  1: 11 41.00
#  2: 18 42.00
#  3: 13 43.00
#  4: 14 44.00
#  5: 15 45.00
#  6: 16 46.00
#  7: 17 47.00
#  8: 18 47.75
#  9: 18 47.75
# 10: 18 47.75
```